# FeedMe SSL error - cURL error 35: SSL connect error

Tags: plugin-feedme, ssl

I'm getting an error when trying to access an endpoint over ssl in FeedMe. eg https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

The error is
`cURL error 35: SSL connect error`

Error reported in web.log is
`[verbb\feedme\base\PluginTrait::error] Test: Unable to reach https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. Message: cURL error 35: SSL connect error (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

I've tried running curl directly from commandline on the server and it runs fine:
`curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` prints the JSON.

`PHP: 7.2.5`
`cURL: 7.19.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the [PHP curl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) version that's on your box is trying to connect to the endpoint using an older SSL protocol (TLS 1.0, 1.1, etc.) and the endpoint requires something higher (TLS 1.2, 1.3, etc.).

http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

The command line version of `curl` is probably using a newer protocol.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. I updated curl on the box to 7.60.0 which uses OpenSSL/1.0.1e. All working now!